# Sorting Algorithm in R

Tags: r, sorting

I had a question related to the sorting algorithm in R.

if I use order() to sort a particular column, the shorter string is not what is sorted first.

To give you an example: I had to sort a column of character type and it puts firearm_weight above fire_weigh and this is not how the dictionary way of sorting strings anyways.

How can I change this while using the order() command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`"_" < "a"` is `TRUE` on my system and locale.

`help("Comparison")` is relevant here:

> Comparison of strings in character vectors is lexicographic within the
>   strings using the collating sequence of the locale in use: see
>   locales. The collating sequence of locales such as en_US is normally
>   different from C (which should use ASCII) and can be surprising.
>   Beware of making any assumptions about the collation order: [...]
>   **Collation of non-letters (spaces, punctuation signs, hyphens,**
>   **fractions and so on) is even more problematic.**

You could substitute "_" with something that is ordered after "z" on your system. E.g., a "µ" on my system.